# How i can upload more than 50MB mp4 videos in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, video, mp4

Am using below code, I have added a maximum size, but it uploads only 1 or 2 mb videos, if i upload a 55 MB video, it takes long  to process but shows a result as blank page:

```
 if (isset($_FILES['video']['name']) && $_FILES['video']['name'] != '') {
            unset($config);
            $date = date("ymd");
            $configVideo['upload_path'] = './videos';
            $configVideo['max_size'] = '602400000';
            $configVideo['allowed_types'] = 'mp4|avi|flv|wmv|';
            $configVideo['overwrite'] = FALSE;
            $configVideo['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
            $video_name = $date.$_FILES['video']['name'];
            $configVideo['file_name'] = $video_name;

            $this->load->library('upload', $configVideo);
            $this->upload->initialize($configVideo);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('video')) {
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            } else {
                $videoDetails = $this->upload->data();

             $schdate = $this->input->post('scheduledate');

                $schdesc = $this->input->post('scheduledes');

                $user = '1';

                $data = array(

                    'name' =>$configVideo['file_name'],

                    'date' => $schdate,

                    'description' => $schdesc,

                   'user_id' => $user

                );

  $this->db->insert('ch_schedule', $data);

                echo "Successfully Uploaded";
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you webserver does not allow to upload such big files it will stop executing when its defined allowed size is reached or the script timeout limit is reached. Look for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`

Comment: But i can't make change in server's php.ini file

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set your `preferences` in your Codeigniter

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';  # This is the upload destination directory
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp4'; #These are the allowed file types
    $config['max_size'] = '100'; #This is the max size allowed
```

Follow this [Official Guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) of Codeigniter

Note :

Also check your `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your php.ini. If you just make this change don't forget stop and start or restart your apache.

### Update :

**If you are working online and can't able to change the php.ini**

Have the following code in your controller

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '200M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '200M');                               
ini_set('max_input_time', 3000);                                
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);
```

Comment: Max size is not working because i want to upload more 50MB videos, Am unable to make changes in server's php.ini file.

Comment: If you're working online and can't able to edit the `php.ini` then do the one i suggested in my answer (I have updated my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Check your upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini

Comment: Thanks for reply,But i have to change php.ini for whole server. How can i add php.ini in codeigniter, or how can i change size for only my site?

Comment: your are woriking local machine or server ?

Comment: try this ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');

Comment: But i can't make change in server's php.ini file.

Comment: put ini_set('post_max_size', '64M'); ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M'); in you file

Answer (score 1):

if your machine is the server
all people that will access and upload large file can do that
if you will change your max file upload in you php ini

here is the link for you php.ini file

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/phpini-file/

Make sure to restart your Apache after amending your php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

Using conventional uploading system to upload **large video** files is not an efficient option . Use ftp to upload large video files .Create a **FTP** on your cpanel.

Comment: He is trying to do this with a script. FTP is not and option here.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you see in the attached screenshot, just go to php setting page
and change `post_max_size` to what you want.