# PHP and Codeigniter large File uploading issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my settings in the  `php.ini` in the live server .

```
post_max_size=1700M,
upload_max_filesize=1500M,
max_execution_time=5000,
max_input_time=5000,
memory_limit=1800M
```

with such higher configuration I can upload only 50mb video . But when I am trying to upload 100mb or more than 100mb after 100% uploading  its says

> Internal Server Error. 
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request

Why this error occurred ?
But in my localhost I can upload video  over 100mb . Give an idea about how to deal with large video upload .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As server support suggested , Now I am using FTP for large file uploading .

Answer (score 0):

It seems similar to the problem described here: [stackoverflow large video upload using CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521118/how-i-can-upload-more-than-50mb-mp4-videos-in-codeigniter). Which can be fixed by updating the Codeigniter `preferences`.

The only thing that puzzles me is that in localhost **the same** (?) code works ok.